# Estimote Telemetry : Unable to track temperature

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, estimote, telemetry

I’m following the example given on the Estimotes developers doc. Code is as follows
I'm facing an 'incompatible type error" when trying to pass the value to scanID variable.

```
package e.user.estimotetelemetry;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.estimote.coresdk.recognition.packets.EstimoteTelemetry;
import com.estimote.coresdk.service.BeaconManager;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private BeaconManager bm;
private String scanId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);


    beaconManager.setTelemetryListener(new BeaconManager.TelemetryListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTelemetriesFound(List<EstimoteTelemetry> telemetries) {
            for (EstimoteTelemetry tlm : telemetries) {
                Log.d("TELEMETRY", "beaconID: " + tlm.deviceId +
                        ", temperature: " + tlm.temperature + " °C");
            }
        }
    });
        }

@Override protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
   //         scanId =  beaconManager.startTelemetryDiscovery();  // This line shows up an incompatibility error as : incompatible types required java.lang.string found void
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
 //   beaconManager.stopTelemetryDiscovery(scanId); //incompatible types required java.lang.string found void
}
}
```

It’ll be great if someone could help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API for telemetry discovery changed slightly, and it looks like the docs haven't been updated accordingly—I've just fixed that.

In the most recent version of the SDK, `startTelemetryDiscovery` no longer returns a `scanId`, and `stopTelemetryDiscovery` no longer accepts one. You just start and stop the scan:

```
@Override protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            beaconManager.startTelemetryDiscovery();
        }
    });
}

@Override protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    beaconManager.stopTelemetryDiscovery();
}
```

Comment: Okay! But I still don't see the temperature in the Debug Log. Why is that?

Comment: Hey! It worked though the temperature isn't tracked as frequently as it should, I could see variations in my Log. Thanks!

Comment: You can experiment with the Telemetry packet's advertising interval (you can configure it with the Estimote app), and the SDK's scanning intervals (see the BeaconManager's setForegroundScanPeriod). Some older Android devices also tend to drop packets.